# Prove that if $\alpha \in BV[a,b]$ and $|\alpha (x)| > M$ then $1/\alpha \in BV[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Prove that if $\alpha \in BV[a,b]$ and for some positive number $M$ we have $|\alpha (x)| > M$ for $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $1/\alpha \in BV[a,b]$.

I am trying to use the definition of bounded variation with the mean value theorem but I'm stuck. What do I do with the inequality?

Comment: If $|\alpha(x)| > M$, then $\frac{1}{ |\alpha(x)|} < \frac{1}{M}$. No, consider any partition of $[a,b]$, and use this trivial bound.

Comment: I am still a little confused. Do I use $\Sigma_{i=1}^n |\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})|$?

Comment: That's right, for any choice of partition $x_i$, you have to prove that the above sum is bounded. Can you do this? (You will need the fact  that $\alpha$ is also of bounded variation). You can also use the fact that very function of bounded variation can be written as the difference of two monotonically increasing functions.

Comment: I understand all these concepts but bringing them all together is a struggle for me. The only thing I am thinking of is that the sigma equation above is less than $1/M$ right off the bat

Comment: All right.  So I'll attempt an answer to this question. We shall see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $|\alpha(x)| > M$, so that the reciprocal is well defined, at the least. Also, since $\alpha$ is of bounded variation, we'll let the constant $C$ be the variation of $\alpha$ (the constant that bounds the sum you gave, for every possible partition).

Next, consider any partition of $[a,b]$, say $x_i$, $0 \leq i \leq n$, where $x_0 = a$ and $x_n = b$.

Now, we basically have to estimate the quantity:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_{i})| = \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\frac{1}{\alpha(x_{i+1})} - \frac{1}{\alpha(x_i)} \right|
$$

Expand the inner bracket:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left|\frac{1}{\alpha(x_{i+1})} - \frac{1}{\alpha(x_i)} \right| = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left|\frac{\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})}{\alpha(x_i) \alpha(x_{i+1})}\right|
$$

Now, since $|\alpha(x)| > M$, it follows that $\frac{1}{|\alpha(x)|} < \frac 1M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Hence:
$$
\left|\frac{\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})}{\alpha(x_i) \alpha(x_{i+1})}\right| \leq |\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})| \frac{1}{|\alpha(x_i)|} \frac{1}{|\alpha(x_{i+1})|} \leq \frac{|\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})|}{M^2}
$$

Summing on both sides:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left|\frac{\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})}{\alpha(x_i) \alpha(x_{i+1})}\right| \leq \frac 1{M^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i+1})| \leq \frac{C}{M^2}
$$

Hence, you get that $\frac 1 \alpha$ is also of bounded variation, since every possible variation is bounded by a finite quantity $\frac C{M^2}$.